# Tint image on hover/pressed

Tags: flutter, button, hover, tint

I have a button widget that accepts a text and an and icon. I want to tint the image when a user hover/taps the button. How can I achieve this? I don't want a ripple effect just a white tint.

```
class SquareButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String icon;
  final String text;

  SquareButton(this.icon, this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () { print(text); },
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            Image(
              image: AssetImage(icon),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Container(
                height: 30,
                child: Text(
                  text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
                  ),
                )
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can try is something like this.

```
class SquareButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String icon;
  final String text;

  SquareButton(this.icon, this.text);

  @override
  _SquareButtonState createState() => _SquareButtonState();
}

class _SquareButtonState extends State<SquareButton> {
  bool isTapped = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) {
        setState(() {
          isTapped = true;
        });
      },
      onTapUp: (_) {
        setState(() {
          isTapped = false;
        });
      },
      onTap: () { print(widget.text); },
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            widget.icon,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            color: isTapped ? Colors.white : null,
          ),
          Container(height: 30, child: Text(widget.text, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,),),),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with @Jigar Patel. But we also need to have `onTapCancle()` while you doing tap and swipe your finger that time `onTapCancle()` will call instead of `onTapUp()` so more improved answer is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'My App',
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isTapped = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (value) {
            setState(() {
              print('onTapDown');
              isTapped = true;
            });
          },
          onTapUp: (value) {
            setState(() {
              print('onTapUp');
              isTapped = false;
            });
          },
          onTapCancel: () {
            setState(() {
              print('onTapCancel');
              isTapped = false;
            });
          },
          child: _getImage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getImage() {
    AssetImage image = AssetImage('images/icon.png');
    return Image(
      image: image,
      width: 100.0,
      height: 100.0,
      color: isTapped ? Colors.deepOrangeAccent : Colors.orange,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with something similar to the other answers but used an overlaying container that I animate to mimic a tap. I feel like there should be a better way in Flutter to solve this kind of problem but maybe not.

```
class SquareButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String icon;
  final String text;

  SquareButton(this.icon, this.text);

  @override
  _SquareButtonState createState() => _SquareButtonState();
}

class _SquareButtonState extends State<SquareButton> {
  Color color = Colors.transparent;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
          setState(() {
            color = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2);
          });
        },
        onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
          setState(() {
            color = Colors.transparent;
          });
        },
        onTapCancel: () {
          setState(() {
            color = Colors.transparent;
          });
        },
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            Image(
              image: AssetImage(widget.icon),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Container(
                height: 30,
                child: Text(
                  widget.text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
                  ),
                )
            ),
            AnimatedContainer(
                color: color,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 50),
            )
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```